# "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm looking for a way to check if the bot can DM someone.

For example:

Me: /dm @someone

The bot: I can't DM this user!

Instead of this error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `try ... catch` statement to catch the exception :

Reference : [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

```
try {
    // Check here if you can DM
} catch (error) {
    // Send message to user ("Can't DM")
}
```

Also, if you are using promises (with the `.send()` function for example) you can catch the error like that :

```
<client>.send("Hey!")
    .catch(() => {
        // Send message to user ("Can't DM")
    });
```